# "How did you know how much time he spent there"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, grammaticality

Is it correct to say: "How did you know how much time he spent there"

Answer (score 2):

As long as you put a question mark on the end, "How did you know how much time he spent there?" is a grammatically correct sentence.

If what you want to know is how the respondent of the question has knowledge of time spent by a man at a location, then it is correct.